# Generate random numbers with specific interval

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I'm trying to generate 3 numbers between 1 and 10. The difference between any two numbers must be smaller/equal to 2. For example: 2, 6, 9 are OK, but 2, 4, 7 are not (because 4 - 2 = 2).

```
private int GetGoodNumber()
{
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int x = 3;
    int randomNumber = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int interval = UnityEngine.Random.Range(2, 7);
        do
        {
            randomNumber = interval + (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 10));
        } while (randomNumber > 10 || x <= 2);
        x = (lastIndex > randomNumber) ? lastIndex - randomNumber : randomNumber - lastIndex;
        lastIndex = randomNumber;
        Debug.Log(randomNumber);
    }
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Unfortunately, my method does not work, does anyone know the problem.

Comment: Keep generating until it matches your specs?

Comment: Just to sum this up: You want a random, ordered interval of numbers between 1 and 10 and they should be at least 3 steps apart?

Comment: yes....not to be the difference between these 3 numbers less than 2

Comment: But you know that you do not return these numbers? You just return the last one, is that intended behaviour?

Comment: Would 2, 8, 4 be ok?

Comment: yes, it's ok, that's it

Comment: difference must be more or equal 3

Comment: the interval is respect every number? or just the last one? I mean 1,6,2 is allowed?

Comment: is not accepted, because 2-1 = 1

Comment: @AnghelinaGuznac but you said my example was ok and 4-2 = 2... That was exactly the purpose of my question!

Comment: this interval must be respected for each generated number

Comment: sorry, there I was wrong

Comment: Please, edit the question to include the details you provided in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabe something like this:

```
    public static List<int> GetRandomNumbers()
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            bool numberFit = false;
            int number = 0;
            do
            {
                number = random.Next(0, 10);
                numberFit = !result.Any(x => x > number - 3 && x < number + 3);

            } while (!numberFit);
            result.Add(number);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: ooo noo, I'm sorry, I got a result like 5,6,8 and it's not good

Comment: This generates a lot of invalid combinations until it finds the right one.

Comment: Your `.Any` could be simplified like `.Any(x => x > number - 3 && x < number + 3)`.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't too many combinations given this rule.

The `firstNumber` must be `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`.

Based on this generate the next between `firstNumber + 3` and `7`.

And the last one by the same logic.

Code:

```
var random = new Random();
var first = random.Next(1, 4 + 1);
var second = random.Next(first + 3, 7 + 1);  
var third = random.Next(second + 3, 10 + 1);
```

Comment: it is not necessary to be exactly +3, it can be +4 or +5, in this case if we make firstNumber + 4, then we get 8, and already 8 + 4 get 12, and it's not good

Comment: because the interval is only between 1 and 10

Comment: @AnghelinaGuznac My code works perfectly. Have you even tried it? The second one is generated from an interval, of course it can be +4 or +5. And all the numbers generated are between 1 and 10.

Comment: well, I'm trying to test

Comment: perfect, really works, thanks a lot. There are not so many combinations here, but only a few.

Comment: keep in mind that the first number MUST BE 1,2,3 or 4, if you try to loop with a random initial number, your code will be freeze :)

Comment: it seems like the numbers don't need to be in ascending order. just take a random permutation of your numbers

Answer (score 1):

I think I would hardcode it to get correct distribution.

```
var x = new [,]
{
    {1, 4, 7},
    {1, 4, 8},
    {1, 4, 9},
    {1, 4, 10},
    {1, 5, 8},
    {1, 5, 9},
    {1, 5, 10},
    {1, 6, 9},
    {1, 6, 10},
    {1, 7, 10},
    {2, 5, 8},
    {2, 5, 9},
    {2, 5, 10},
    {2, 6, 9},
    {2, 6, 10},
    {2, 7, 10},
    {3, 6, 9},
    {3, 6, 10},
    {3, 7, 10},
    {4, 7, 10}
};
```